# Why the Simpler "How do I write a good question" Help Page?

Tags: discussion, help-center

I just  noticed that a  help page that  I often link  to new
users, *“[How do I write a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”*, was edited.

Compared  to the  [previous  version](http://web.archive.org/web/20180613012230/https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it  has much  less
information. Why? Any advantages?

Comment: uh... That is a very good question.

Comment: @Dukeling In that case, a both pages could exist. The complete version used before had a lot of good info, links and examples. A truly complete and easy to link guide. It is a great loss.

Comment: It's quicker for the new users to not-read it.

Comment: It's been reverted to the default page that sites use when they have no more specific information. (Why this happened I don't know.)

Comment: Nice catche. It's been fixed now though, voting to close as no longer reproducible so users aren't confused going forward.

Comment: Simple is always* better. (* except when it's not)

Comment: Wow, people have been complaining, that is too complex so new users won't read it. Now they are complaining that it's more concise.... Time to reevaluate life choices then.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's coming back very soon.  There was an accidental deletion and caching at play here.